# How to get/find the function being called from a DOM element or variable in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm not sure how or if this is something that can be done.  I have a page that is being created via a CMS.  There are alot of files i.e.: `includes`, `.LESS` and `.js` files.  Depending on the template chosen, the css rule sets the `aside#socialicons` element to "display:none".  However, this rule is being overwritten by an inline css style of `"display:block"` set on the same element on the fly.

I have looked through several files (`.css, .less` and `.js`) to try and find how this property is being added on the fly so that I could change it.

In the global.js, a variable is declared and defined as follows:

```
g = g || {};
g = {
selectors: {
        socialbox: "aside#socialicons",
            ....
}
```

Line by line, I went manually looking through all the `.js` files to find the `g.selector.socialbox` variable. I was hoping to find the function that is manipulating it.  I have not found it yet. I also looked through all the css/less files for the selector `aside#socialicons` and could only find the css rule setting it to `display:none;visibility:hidden;`.

Tell me folks, if a function is indeed modifying this element, is there a way in the Developer Tools Console of Chrome or Firebug where I can find what function is being called to add the `display:block` to the `aside#socialicons/g.selector.socialbox` element?  Can assertions work? If any of these methods can work, would you please let me know how it is done?

Thanks very much.

**UPDATE:**
All js files have been compressed and compiled into one .js file for better performance.  The page is using about 10 javascripts and 10 javascript library files.  I can view source to see the files being loaded, but because the element has been defined in different files using different names, for example `g.selectors.socialbox`, or `g.socialbox`, it's getting confusing trying to follow what variable is the `aside#socialicons` element.  In firebug, I can search for the element and/or the variable in all files, but if the variable has been renamed, I'm getting very lost.  All help is welcome.  I did not write this code.

Thanks very  much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `Elements` tab of Developer Tools, right-click on the element and select `Break on Attribute Modification`. Then wait for the breakpoint to hit, and you can check the stack trace to see where it's being modified from.

Comment: Barmar, in the sources tab, I have located the element (variable) in the javascript. However, when I right-click, there is no option for `Break on Attribute Modification`, there is one for `Local Modifications`.  When I click the latter option, Breakpoints tab shows "_No Breakpoints_".

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong tab name, I meant Elements.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar.  I just looked it up here http://www.elijahmanor.com/7-chrome-tips-developers-designers-may-not-know/

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with the above link reference, Barmar, but when I right-click on the element in the Elements tab, I don't know what to do next.  In the article listed in the above link, it appears that the user knows what .js file has the code for the function being called.  I suppose my expectation was to be led to the function via a particular pane in the Dev Tools that is adding the display property on this element.  What is the expected result of selecting `Break on Attribute Modification`?  I am not sure what to do after this action.  Thanks.

Comment: When you selec that, it tells the browser to stop whenever that element is modified. When that happens, it will go to the Sources tab and show you the code that was executing at the time of modification. The Call Stack section in the sidebar will show the calling history, and you can move down the stack to find the function in your application that caused it.

Comment: Hmmm, `Break on Attribute Modification` only shows the element that was modified in the _DOM Breakpoints_ panel. ??  This is known since you must right-click it for that result. What I need to know is how to find the function that is injecting the `display:block` on this element.  I didn't write the code, it's a new project for me and the author is long gone.  Upvotes to posters, they are helping.  I'll keep looking, too.

Comment: The link I posted above shows screenshots of chrome from 3 years ago, but it is a bit helpful.

Comment: Barmar,  I didn't see your post while I was typing mine.  I'll clear my cache and see if I get the results you posted since when I right-click, I have to manually open the `Sources` tab and then ctrl+O to open a file.  I'm not seeing any results in `Call Stack` either, only `DOM Breakpoints` opens.

Comment: You have to set the breakpoint before the element is modified, then wait for the breakpoint to be hit. Then you can look in the Call Stack to see what part of the program performed the modification.

Comment: _"set the breakpoint before the element is modified, then wait for the breakpoint to be hit"_.  The `display:none` is injected on the element on the fly.  By the time I select the element in the `Elements` tab, it has been modified.  The `Sources` tab does not open.  Am I using the wrong feature (`Break on Attribute Modifications`) or am I using the wrong tab? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Set a regular source code breakpoint at the beginning of the first JS script that's loaded, so you can examine the DOM and set a modification breakpoint before any modifications are made by Javascript.

Comment: Revisited this question today and have a better understanding of javascript and the answer and explanation @Barmar gave.  Selected his as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way is to open up Chrome, and from the debug console type: `getEventListeners(object)`. It will show you all of the event listeners attached to that object and what the functions are.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#geteventlistenersobject

Good Luck

Comment: If jQuery is being used, this may not be very helpful. Everything will just point to some generic jQuery methods, not the functions in the application.

Comment: Thanks, DondeEstaMiCulo for the link reference to Developer Tools API. It is very helpful and I will try it out today.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find `g.selector.socialbox`, try looking for instances of g.selector. It may be because they are looping over every attribute of `g.selector`, rather than calling `g.selector.socialbox` directly.

Try setting some breakpoints at various points in global.js. As you step through them it will give you a better idea of where the function call is happening. They can be set via the Script tab in Firefox, or the Sources tab in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I'm not that  good at how to step through the code yet, other than using some tutorials, I haven't had to do this type of debugging yet, but this is what I definitely need to learn more how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Chris, likely not the best answer, but it hard to answer not knowing the CMS in question.

You could overide in JS, but CSS would be simpler

```
#divwithinlinestyle { display:block !important; }
```

Comment: I meant `display:none` as per your question, but you get the idea

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  I voted up for your answer because yours offers a  "quick & dirty" fix for this issue and I can use it.  Although I do want to know how to find out what is causing the property change when the page loads using the Developer Tools.